# How to draw line on XCTest

Tags: line, draw, ui-automation, xctest

Currently I change my test solution from UI Automation to XCTest. My application could allow the user to draw line inside an area.

So in my previous test at UI Automation, I could draw using method of

```
dragFromToForDuration(startPoint, endPoint, duration),
```

but in XCTest I find one, but not workable for me:

```
func press(forDuration duration: TimeInterval, thenDragTo otherElement:XCUIElement)
```

I use this method like this:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let cell = app.toolbars.buttons["line"]
let start = cell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector.init(dx:0 , dy: 200)
let finish = = cell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector.init(dx:400 , dy: 300)
start.press(forDuration: 2, thenDragTo: finish)
```

Is any problem about my above code? Obviously this method could draw straight line, how about curve?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

First set your test view's accessibility identifier, then in your test code :

```
    let view = app.otherElements["test_view"] // "test_view" is test view's accessibility identifier
    let origin = view.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .zero)
    let point1 = origin.withOffset(CGVector(dx: 80, dy: 80))
    let point2 = origin.withOffset(CGVector(dx: 200, dy: 200))

    point1.press(forDuration: 2, thenDragTo: point2)
```

this will draw a line from (80, 80) to (200, 200).